# Cannot trigger onClickListener on a LinearLayout with linkfied TextViews

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, linkify

I'm developing a list view in which each cell is a LinearLayout with other views inside it. I have also set the onClickListener of the cells to take the user to another Activity.

The problem is that one of the views inside is a TextView in which I apply the Linkify function. When the TextView happens to have a link in its text, I cannot trigger the onClickListener anymore, unless I click on another view of the LinearLayout. This problem also applies to the highlighting feature.

Does anyone knows what may be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying the Linkify function inside of your getView() Override, I would wonder if it's just automatically setting the "Clickable" type methods on the view being passed to it. Right after Linkify, you could try calling setClickable(false), setFocusable(false), setFocusableInTouchMode(false) all on the view that was Linkified.

Comment: To further understand this, doing the above makes the listview item clickable around the view that had it's focus set to false. Is there a way to return focus to whole listview item including all the views in it?